# Set up an automated R script in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I have an R Script that does a lot of heavy lifting and occasionally crashes

I'd like to run it with Python and try again if it fails (with a reasonable upper limit of attempts).

Ideally, I would do this from Python 3.x.

This is my code so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript (I added this code to the top of my file)

subprocess.call("/pathto/MyrScript.r")
```

My script prints out a bunch of helpful diagnostic info.

This is what I'd like to be able to do:

1. Start the script from Python [done]
2. Try again if the script fails while it's running [not done]

I'm thinking I might be able to do #2 with something like

```
try:
  subprocess.call("/pathto/MyrScript.r")
except:
  i+=1
  if i > 5: 
    print("Tried >5 times")
  else: 
    subprocess.call("/pathto/MyrScript.r")
```

Can you please help give me context on #2? Thanks!

Comment: Could I pass an argument from python into the R script?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in shell, if the execution is successful it returns 0. Any return code greater than 0 indicates an error of some sort.

You can read more about bash outputs here (assuming you are working on linux env): [https://askubuntu.com/questions/892604/meaning-of-exit-0-exit-1-and-exit-2-in-a-bash-script#:~:text=With%20bash%20commands%20the%20return,return%20to%20the%20command%20line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892604/meaning-of-exit-0-exit-1-and-exit-2-in-a-bash-script#:%7E:text=With%20bash%20commands%20the%20return,return%20to%20the%20command%20line).

So if your subprocess call is successful it should return 0.

```py
output=1
while output!=0:
   try:
        output=subprocess.call('fileaddress')
   except:
        i+=1
        print(f'Tried {i} times')
```

You could pass the arguments to R script, but you would have to look into your R script to accept arguments from terminal. Actually you are not passing arguments from python, but with subprocess module python is executing bash commands. So if you are able to execute your R script from terminal using arguments, you can execute the same using subprocess but pass the command and arguments as list, for example: `subprocess.call(['ls', '-l']`

Comment: I ended up using the R Script command and running from the R Terminal